# Dynamic change of XACML policies in WSO2

Tags: wso2, xacml3, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Is it possible to create XACML policy and upload in WSO2 identity server(PDP) programmatically?

I want to create and upload policy in WSO2 identity server(PDP) but i do not want to use WSO2 Management Console screen for creating and uploading policies. I want to use my own screen.

If it is possible, Please let me know sample example also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your policies through SOAP web service exposed through following WSDL, there is a method for adding addPolicy/addPolicies

```
https://localhost:9443/services/EntitlementPolicyAdminService?wsdl
```

Above service is an admin service, and it's hided by default, you have to enable it to use.

1. Open carbon.xml file which can be found at /repository/conf
   directory and set following property to “false”

   ```
   <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
   ```
2. Then restart server and access above url from your browser to see the WSDL
3. You can find the sample client from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pap/5.X.X/), this is for Identity Server 5.0.0